# If $f$ and $g$ are integrable, then $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is integrable with respect to product measure.

Tags: measure-theory, integration

I have to show that $h$ is measurable as well as $\int h d(\mu \times \nu) < \infty$ .

I tried showing by contradiction that $\int h$ had to be finite but I'm stuck with showing how it is measurable.

Comment: $h$ does note have to be finite. Its integral has to be finite.

Answer (score 8):

**1- Measurability:**

**Fact:** a function is measurable if and only if it is the pointwise limit of a sequence of [simple functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function).

So take $s_n, t_n$ simple such that $f(x)=\lim s_n(x)$ for every $x$ and $g(y)=\lim t_n(y)$  for every $y$. Then $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)=\lim s_n(x)t_n(y)$ for every $(x,y)$. It only remains to observe that each $(x,y)\longmapsto s_n(x)t_n(y)$ is a simple function to conclude that $h$ is measurable. This follows readily from
$$
1_A(x)1_B(y)=1_{A\times B}(x,y).
$$

**2- Integrability:**

We will use the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), asuming you have not proved Fubini yet. Otherwise, this is trivial. But how can you have Fubini if you don't have measurability?

Take two nondecreasing sequences of nonnegative simple functions $s_n(x)$, $t_n(y)$ converging pointwise to $|f(x)|$ and $|g(y)|$ respectively. Then $s_n(x)t_n(y)$ is a nondecreasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions converging pointwise to $|h|$. By the monotone convergence theorem
$$
\int |h| \;d(\mu\times \nu)=\lim\int s_n(x)t_n(y)\;d(\mu\times \nu)(x,y).
$$
By definition of the product measure 
$$
\int 1_{A\times B}\;d(\mu\times \nu)=(\mu\times \nu) (A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu (B)=\int 1_Ad\mu\int 1_Bd\nu.
$$
By linearity, this extends to simple functions. Hence, by monotone convergence again,
$$
\int s_n(x)t_n(y)\;d(\mu\times \nu)(x,y)=\int s_nd\mu\int t_nd\nu\longrightarrow \int |f|d\mu\int |g|d\mu<\infty.
$$
So $h$ is integrable with
$$
\int |h| \;d(\mu\times \nu)=\int |f|d\mu\int |g|d\nu.
$$ 
Note that applying the above to $f_{\pm}$ and $g_{\pm}$, we can deduce
$$
\int h \;d(\mu\times \nu)=\int fd\mu\int gd\nu.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $\int f(x)g(y) d(\mu\times \nu)=\int f(x)(\int g(y)d\nu)d\mu$.

Comment: But I need to prove that also, so I need h to be integrable in order to use Fubini's theorem

Comment: @user54358 To show the hint, you actually use Tonelli's theorem (if I got a dollar for every time I point out that difference... :)).